# Check empty numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

For learning purpose, I would like to know how to check the empty numbers (or replaced with letters) from random numbers.

I put numbers and letters into an array:

```
var numb = [1, 7, 3, a, 4];
```

In this case we don't know the highest number or the lowest number.

I want to check the empty numbers starting from number 2 to the highest (**result 2, 5, and 6**).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "empty" numbers.

Comment: why don't you replace 'your empty number' (OR MAY BE UNDEFINED VALUE) from the array? then you can get the highest value

Comment: In this case I want to get number 2, 5, and 6 from the above array.

Comment: loop the array, check if the element/item is a 'number' or not, if not replace it!

Comment: A small suggestion: Next time try to show what you've tried (some code) to accomplish your task! Don't expect people to write code for you! ;) Happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over your *Array* to find the maximum `max`, then iterate `max - 1 - minumum` times testing for the existence of numbers in the *Array*.

```
function foo(arr) {
    var bar = [],
        i,
        max = -Infinity;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) // loop 1
        if (arr[i] === +arr[i]) // simple check if number, throw away NaN
            if (arr[i] > max)
                max = arr[i];
    while (max-- > 2) // loop 2, you said 2 is minimum
        if (arr.indexOf(max) === -1)
           bar.unshift(max);
    return bar;
}

foo([1, 7, 3, 'baz', 4]); // [2, 5, 6]
```

I also assumed all your numbers will be integers.

Comment: `max = -Infinity;` why `-` ? Why Infinity at all

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan any number (except `NaN` and itself) is greater than `-Infinity`. Also, `Math.max(); // -Infinity`. Any loop where `-Infinity` is the highest iteration count will immediately stop.